# How can I simplify these multiple/similar click events in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I have several buttons on my page for which I'm assigning similar click events. The code below works fine, but is there a way I can loop/simplify the repetitive blocks below? I tried a for loop but it didn't work.

```
var functionName = "step";

$("#stepbox1").click(function(){
$("#step1").show();                    
$("#stepswrapper section").not("#step1").hide();
$("#stepbox1").addClass("stepboxactive");
$("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox1").removeClass("stepboxactive");
myFunctions[functionName + 1]();
});

$("#stepbox2").click(function(){
$("#step2").show();                    
$("#stepswrapper section").not("#step2").hide();
$("#stepbox2").addClass("stepboxactive");
$("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox2").removeClass("stepboxactive");
myFunctions[functionName + 2]();
});

$("#stepbox3").click(function(){
$("#step3").show();                    
$("#stepswrapper section").not("#step3").hide();
$("#stepbox3").addClass("stepboxactive");
$("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox3").removeClass("stepboxactive");
myFunctions[functionName + 3]();
});

// And another three of those…
```

This loop will NOT work:

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
$("#stepbox" + i).click(function(){
$("#step" + i).show();                     
$("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + i).hide();
$("#stepbox" + i).addClass("stepboxactive");
$("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + i).removeClass("stepboxactive");
myFunctions[functionName + i]();
});
}
```

Comment: Adding HTML is fine, you just need to indent it so StackOverflow will render it as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the access to `i` variable with closures:

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    $("#stepbox" + i).click((function (j) { // create the closure here
        return function () {
            // now work with `j` instead of `i`
            $("#step" + j).show();
            $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + j).hide();
            $("#stepbox" + j).addClass("stepboxactive");
            $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + j).removeClass("stepboxactive");
            myFunctions[functionName + j]();
        };
    }(i))); // pass the `i` variable to closure
}
```

Comment: Thanks ROX. This worked beautifully without changing the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `div[id*=stepbox]` to retrieve the array of divx since they all have `stepbox` common in their IDs. Then you can get the index of the each element and use it in the rest of the code. (It is a 0-based array that is why I added +1 at the beginning).

```
 $("div[id*=stepbox]").click(function(){
    int myIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $("#step" + myIndex).show();                    
    $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + myIndex).hide();
    $("#stepbox" + myIndex).addClass("stepboxactive");
    $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + myIndex).removeClass("stepboxactive");
    myFunctions[functionName + myIndex]();
 });
```

Comment: The buttons are actually divs, not buttons:

<div id="stepbox1" class="stepboxactive"><strong>Step 1</strong><br />Your name</div>
<div id="stepbox2"><strong>Step 2</strong><br />Divider</div>
<div id="stepbox3"><strong>Step 3</strong><br />Font</div>
<div id="stepbox4"><strong>Step 4</strong><br />Shapes</div>
<div id="stepbox5"><strong>Step 5</strong><br />Color</div>
<div id="stepbox6"><strong>Step 6</strong><br />Export it</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your HTML then here is a cleaner approach:

```
<div id="stepbox1" class="stepboxactive stepbox" data-box-id="1">
  <strong>Step 1</strong><br />
  Your name
</div>
<div id="stepbox2" class="stepbox" data-box-id="2">
  <strong>Step 2</strong><br />
  Divider
</div>
<div id="stepbox3" class="stepbox" data-box-id="3">
  <strong>Step 3</strong><br />
  Font
</div>
<div id="stepbox4" class="stepbox" data-box-id="4">
  <strong>Step 4</strong><br />
  Shapes
</div>
<div id="stepbox5" class="stepbox" data-box-id="5">
  <strong>Step 5</strong><br />
  Color
</div>
<div id="stepbox6" class="stepbox" data-box-id="6">
  <strong>Step 6</strong><br />
  Export it
</div>
```

Then your code can attach to any div with the class `stepbox` and it can get it's ID from a `data` attribute (you can see how you can extend this system to non-sequential IDs or even alphanumeric IDs.  Your code might look something like this:

```
$(".stepbox").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('box-id');

  $("#step"+id).show();                    
  $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step"+id).hide();
  $("#stepbox"+id).addClass("stepboxactive");
  $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox"+id).removeClass("stepboxactive");
  myFunctions[functionName + id]();
});
```

Comment: Great approach Jason. I never used the data attribute, so not only your approach worked great but was also excellent for my learning.